# Mutable variable memory location

Tags: c++, mutable, storage-class-specifier

I have following understanding of mutable variables in C++.

1. Its a special storage class.
2. A mutable variable can be modified by a constant object.
3. An example of a case where you want to use mutable variable will be a case where you don't want to execute an expensive operation to get a result unless specifically asked. if specifically asked, your program will execute the operation once  and cache the result in mutable variable.

My question is in terms of memory. Where will compiler store mutable variable in memory? Since its modifiable, then it will not be "read only" memory for sure.

Comment: Thanks all for your valuable comments!

Answer (score 3):

`mutable` ([mutable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cv)) is just a type qualifier for the compiler like `const` or `volatile`.
The members of a class are stored on a continuous chunk of memory (except for the static ones). If you define a member as `const`, it doesn't mean that the compiler will place it in a RO memory. `const` declaration won't effect anything during the run time, it is just a keyword for the compiler to perform appropriate checks and optimizations during compilation.
Once you define a class (or a method) as `const` but you still need to modify a specific member of that class (like mutex or like you mentioned - to cache a value) you let the compiler know that this specific member is `mutable`, otherwise you will get a compilation error.

Answer (score 2):

Presumably this is compiler specific but I imagine most compilers would simply choose to always locate classes (the entire class) with mutable members into non-const memory to allow for this.

Answer (score 2):

It is entirely up to the compiler, which may perform escape analysis and determine the object can never be modified, in which case it may be written in the `read-only` section of the binary.  The `mutable` storage class specifier only relaxes a compile time requirement.

Objects are required to be allocated in declaration order though, so regardless of storage class specifier, all variables are in the same region of memory.  However, nothing would preclude a `read-only` bit from being set on a `const` region of bytes if the machine supported it.

Answer (score 1):

All members of a class have a size (determined by `sizeof`) which is at least `1`.    That is true for `mutable` members as well, and means that all class members must occupy some range of locations in memory.

The only thing that is special about a `mutable` member is that its value can be changed, even if it is within a `const` object.    It is up to the compiler how it achieves that.  Typically, the compiler enforces constness at compile time. In other words, if an object is `const`, its members are logically `const` as well, and an attempt is made to modify (or call a non-`const` operation) on any member, then the code will not compile unless that member is `mutable`.

There is actually no need for a `const` object, or its members, to be popped into readonly memory at run time.   If that is actually done, then there will need to be some special treatment to allow its `mutable` members to be changed, even if changes to other members are prevented.   For example, all of the object's members might be placed in modifiable memory, and only the non-mutable ones marked (e.g. with operating system support) so they cannot be changed at runtime.

A common reason for using mutable members is to store the results from expensive operations that are repeatable (give the same results for the same inputs).   If the results aren't needed, the expensive operations are also not needed.   If the result needs to be accessed repeatedly, then mutable members allow storing the results the first time, rather than repeatedly doing the expensive operations.